# How to read data from Excel File saved in an blob in azure with EPPlus library

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, epplus

I'm trying to read my excel files saved in my azure storage container like this

```
  string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING");          

  BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

  BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("concursos");

  foreach (BlobItem blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobs())
  {     

    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);

    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

    using (var stream=blobClient.OpenRead(new BlobOpenReadOptions(true)))
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
    {
     ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
     int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;  
     int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
     for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
     {
        for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
        {
         Console.WriteLine(" Row:" + row + " column:" + col + " Value:" + worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString().Trim());
        }
    }
```

But the sentence

```
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
```

throws me an error:System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' worksheet was null

I debug an see fine my stream an my package

[image: debug]

The excels in blobs are like this one .xls

[image: excels]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @kavyasaraboju-MT I have updated my post with the content example of one of my blobs. The excel has a worksheet "Hoja1" with columns and rows filled. When I check package.Workbook.Worksheets.Count() I get 0. And package.Stream.Length=0 too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the file extension of the excel files in blobs

Only works fone with .xlsx not with .xls

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check if worksheet is **empty** .This error occurs if there is empty sheet with empty coumns and rows.

I tried to reproduce the same
Initially I tried to read a excel sheet with EPplus , where starting column and rows are  filled and **not empty** and could execute and read successfully using the same code as yours.

[image]

Then I removed column1 to be empty and stored in blob and tried to read it and got null reference exception.

[image]

**The Dimension object of the ExcelWorksheet will be null if the worksheet was just initialized and is empty .**
**And so throws null reference exception**, AFAIK , the only way is to **check if files are empty**  or to **add content to it** before accessing them so that if columns are empty , it would not throw exception.

```
worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Some text value";
```

Same way try to add worksheet, to avoid  exception if in case there are no sheets in container blob.

```
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = new ExcelPackage().Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
```

> **This code will not throw an exception since the Dimension object was initialized by adding content to the worksheet.If the loaded
> ExcelWorksheet already contains data, you will not face this issue.**

```
       ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
      //or ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
                   
    // Add below line to add new sheet , if no sheets are present and returning null exception
//ExcelWorksheet worksheet = new ExcelPackage().Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

    //Add below line to add column and row , if sheet is empty and returning  null exception
       worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = " This is the end of worksheet";
                   
              int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
              int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;

               for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
                {
                   for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
                     {

                       Console.WriteLine(" Row:" + row + " column:" + col + " Value:" + worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString().Trim());
                            }
                        }
```

**You can alternatively check if the value is null.**

```
if(worksheet.cells[row,column].value != null)
   {
         //proceed with code
   }
```